# rxjava emit inner observable once it starts emitting

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Is there any easy way to create an observable of observables that will only emit once the inner observable emits? For example:

say we have a magical observable that does this

```
Observable<Observable<Integer>> magicOuterObservable;
```

subscribe to outer

```
magicOuterObservable.subscribe(subscriber)
```

offer inner observable to outer

```
magicOuterObservable.onNext(inner);
```

nothing yet

```
subscriber.assertNoValues();
```

offer value to inner observable

```
inner.onNext(1)
```

outer emits

```
subscriber.assertValue(inner);
```

Terminal events would not cause an emission. Only the first inner emissions really.

Any ideas?

If anyone is curious, this for a potentially over-engineered pull to refresh handler.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reasonable enough solution to this, if anybody wants to know, it looks something like this:

```
innerSubject
    .map(inner -> inner.replay().autoConnect())
    .flatMap(inner -> Observable.create(emitter ->
        inner.take(1).subscribe(ignored -> e.onNext(inner))));
```

I think there is some work to be done around subscription management depending on how this is used, as obviously the inner subscription should be bound to the outer one.

Comment: I think `Observable.create(emitter ->inner.take(1).subscribe(ignored -> e.onNext(inner))))` is better to be `inner.take(1).map(ignored->inner)`.